# groups generated by two elements of order 3

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I'd like to know whether it is possible to find a characterization (cardinality?) of the set of finite, non-abelian groups generated by two elements $a$ and $b$ whose order is $3$? Is it the same task than finding all possible relations between $a$ and $b$ (for instance $aabba=bab$)?
Thanks by advance for any comment

Comment: Casting your question into the language of relations is dangerous. For instance, suppose you were asking whether a group obtained from the free product $\mathbb{Z/3} * \mathbb{Z/3} = \langle a,b \, | \, a^3 = b^3 = Id\rangle$ by adding further relations is finite. It seems highly unlikely to me that one can carry out an enumeration in this fashion. This is uncomfortably close to a known undecidability theorem: there exists no algorithm to decide from a general finite presentation whether the group is finite. But I don't know whether a version of that theorem exists in your special case.

Comment: I would be very suprised if it was possible to obtain such a characterization. It might be possible for finite simple groups, and I would expect most of the to have this property.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe interesting to know, this touches the famous [Burnside problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_problem), posed by William Burnside in 1902 and one of the oldest and most influential questions in group theory. It asks whether a finitely generated group in which every element has finite order must necessarily be finite.